# How do I find the maximum value of an object's attribute that occurs exactly twice in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, attributes, max

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  If I want to find the maximum number of a numeric attribute of my model, I can do

```
max_num = my_objects_arr.maximum(:numeric_attr)
```

but how would I find the maximum number of attributes whose values occur exactly twice in my array?  That is, let's say my objects array has three objects

```
obj1 - numeric_attr = 3
obj2 - numeric_attr = 3
obj3 - numeric_attr = 4
```

The maximum of the attributes above that occur exactly twice would be "3".  Although "4" is the maximum of all attributes, it only occurs once in the array.

Comment: Oh, "numeric_attr" is the name of the field.  So an object can only have one field named "numeric_attr".  DOes that make sense?

Comment: `arr.uniq.select { |e| arr.count(e) == 2 }.max`

Comment: @iceツ this is `O(N²)` in the worst case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]

array.group_by { |e| e } # group_by(&:itself) since 2.3
     .select { |_, v| v.count == 2 }
     .keys
     .max
#⇒ 3
```

For objects and attributes:

```
my_objects_arr.group_by { |o| o.numeric_attr }
              .select { |_, v| v.count == 2 }
              .keys
              .max
```

To get the objects themselves:

```
my_objects_arr.group_by { |o| o.numeric_attr }
              .select { |_, v| v.count == 2 }
              .max_by(&:first)
              .last
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using rails calculations e.g. `#maximum` this should work for you

```
my_objects_arr
  .group(:numeric_attr)
  .having("count(numeric_attr) = 2")
  .maximum(:numeric_attr)
```

This will find the maximum value of `numeric_attr` by grouping them by the `numeric_attr` and selecting the `numeric_attr` that have exactly 2

SQL estimation

```
SELECT 
  MAX(numeric_attr)
FROM 
  [SOME TABLE]
GROUP BY 
  numeric_attr
HAVING 
  COUNT(numeric_attr) = 2
```

Comment: For Rails this is a way to go. _Sidenote:_ please respect people reading from smartphones, format lines shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|n,h| h[n] += 1}.select {|_,nbr| nbr == 2}.keys.max
  #=> 3
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that creates a hash `h` with a default value of zero. That means that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns zero (without altering the hash). This refers to the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), not to be confused with [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).